# Find element by name using wildcard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to type into a field using a wildcard. I have 5 pages which all collect the same information but the fields are incremented 1 through 5. My idea was to find the element by grabbing the common name such as "first_name" or "last_name" but I keep getting the "element not found" error in my attempts. Below is what the input looks like.

```
<input class="a-field" id="textfield_123" type="text" name="person_1_first_name" value="">
```

I have tried the following but it returns "unable to locate element".

```
driver.find_element_by_name('//input[contains(@name, "middle_Name")]').clear()
```

Comment: If you know what the string will be, why use a wildcard? Why not `"the_part_you_know{}".format(number)`?

Comment: @reedinator I would like to write using a wildcard so I can run the same code on each page instead of re-writing the procedure five times.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a function to avoid rewriting the procedure n times??

Comment: xpath `//input[contains(@name,'middle_name')]` looks good. But what I predict is there might be some frames/windows in your application. Which is causing issue to identify the element. Hope you waited enough time to load the page completely before checking the element.

Comment: @supputri Using `driver.find_element_by_name('person_1_first_name')` works so it's not a rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
def wildcard = “string”

driver.find_element_by_name(f”//input[contains(@name, ‘{wildcard}’]”).clear()
```

I have no clue where they got this from but having the “f” before the first quote in the xpath makes it accept variables . Let me know if that helps